# How do you join multiple arrays of different length together?

Tags: rust, blockchain

I need to join multiple arrays of u8's that are of different sizes together to create a block header for blockchain related stuff, I tried the concat method but that only works if all the arrays are of the same length.

```
pub struct Block{
    
    pub prev_block_hash: [u8;32],
    pub timestamp : [u8;8],
    pub difficuly : [u8;4], 
    pub block_height : [u8;4],
    pub nonce: [u8;4],
    pub version : [u8;4]

}
pub fn create_header(&self) -> [u8 ; 56]{
        let buffer :[ u8 ; 56] = [0;56];
        let buffer_as_vec  = [self.version, self.prev_block_hash,self.timestamp,self.difficuly,self.block_height,self.nonce].concat();

        buffer_as_vec.try_into().expect("Wrong size")
       
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn the arrays into slices:

```rust
let buffer_as_vec = [
    self.version.as_slice(),
    self.prev_block_hash.as_slice(),
    self.timestamp.as_slice(),
    self.difficuly.as_slice(),
    self.block_height.as_slice(),
    self.nonce.as_slice(),
]
.concat();
```

Or

```rust
let buffer_as_vec = [
    &self.version[..],
    &self.prev_block_hash[..],
    &self.timestamp[..],
    &self.difficuly[..],
    &self.block_height[..],
    &self.nonce[..],
]
.concat();
```